# Square of normal distribution with specific variance

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution

What is the distribution of the square of a normally distributed random variable $X^2$ with $X\sim N(0,\sigma^2/4)$?
I know $\chi^2(1)=Z^2$ is a valid argument for when squaring a **standard normal** distribution, but what about the case of non-unit variance?

Comment: Why not just calculate this directly from the Normal equation, then plot the resulting function?

Comment: I am looking for a theoretical explanation here...

Comment: Write $Z = \frac{X}{\sigma/2}$... or equivalently $X=\frac{\sigma}{2}\cdot Z$. Can you do it now?

Comment: $\sigma^2/4∗\chi^2(1)$? So, nothing of fancy uncentered chi square stuff?

Comment: As long as the mean is $0$, no noncentral chi-square stuff; just plain vanilla _scaled_ $\chi^2$ distribution as Glen_b points out.

Comment: I think one of the above comments is wrong. It is not true that $$
X = \sigma/2 *Z$$.

Answer (score 42):

To close this one:

$$ X\sim N(0,\sigma^2/4) \Rightarrow \frac {X^2}{\sigma^2/4}\sim \mathcal \chi^2_1 \Rightarrow X^2 = \frac {\sigma^2}{4}\mathcal \chi^2_1 = Q\sim \text{Gamma}(1/2, \sigma^2/2)$$

with

$$E(Q) = \frac {\sigma^2}{4},\;\; \text{Var}(Q) = \frac {\sigma^4}{8}$$

**RESPONSE TO QUESTION IN THE COMMENT**

If
$$X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2/4)$$

then
$$\frac {X^2}{\sigma^2/4} \sim \mathcal \chi^2_{1,NC}(\lambda=\mu^2),$$

where $\mathcal \chi^2_{1,NC}(\lambda)$ represents a [*Non-Central* Chi-square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution) with one degree of freedom, and $\lambda$ is the non-centrality parameter. Then

$$X^2 =\frac{\sigma^2}{4} \mathcal \chi^2_{1,NC}(\lambda)$$

can be treated as a version of the [Generalized Chi-square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_chi-squared_distribution).

Comment: if mu =/= 0, how will this turn out?