# What is the distribution of the ratio between independent Beta and Gamma random variables?

Tags: distributions, gamma-distribution, beta-distribution, ratio

What would be the distribution of the following equation:

$$y = \frac{a}{(a+d)^2}$$

where $a, d$ $\sim$ $\Gamma(M,c)$. Additionally, $a$ and $d$ are independent random variables.

Comment: Your title doesn't match the body of your question -- $y$ is not the ratio of independent chi-square variates.

Comment: @Glen_b, could you give me better title,please?

Comment: Can you say how the calculation arises? That might lead to a better description.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For independent $a, d\sim\operatorname{\Gamma}(M,c)$, a remarkable result is that $U=a+d$ and $V=a/(a+d)$ are also independent. In addition, $U\sim\operatorname{\Gamma}(2M, c)$, $V\sim\mathrm{B}(M,M)$. See for example Ch.25, Sec. 2 of Johnson, Kotz, and Balakrishnan's 
[*Continuous Univariate Distributions, Volume 2*](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471584940.html) for some details.

Now this says $$Y=\frac{a}{(a+d)^2}=\frac{1}{a+d}\frac{a}{a+d}=\frac{V}{U}$$ is a ratio between independent Gamma and Beta random variables. Nadarajah and Kotz's [*On the Product and Ratio of Gamma and Beta Random Variables*](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10182-005-0214-9) and Nadarajah's [*The Gamma Beta Ratio Distribution*](https://doi.org/10.1214/10-bjps128) have discussed this distribution thoroughly.

**EDIT:** Using the CDFs and PDFs given in the articles mentioned above, we can derive (simplified with Wolfram Alpha) the CDF of $Y$ as: $$F_Y(y) = 1-\frac{\Gamma(3M)}{2(cy)^{2M}\Gamma(M+1)\Gamma(4M)}{}_2F_2\left(2M, 3M; 2M+1,4M; -\frac{1}{cy}\right),$$ and the PDF of $Y$ as: $$f_Y(y)=\frac{\Gamma(3M)}{y(cy)^{2M}\Gamma(M)\Gamma(4M)}{}_1F_1\left(3M; 4M; -\frac{1}{cy}\right)$$ where ${}_1F_1$ and ${}_2F_2$ are the generalized hyper-geometric functions. These expressions are in accordance with @wolfies's result.

Comment: So maybe the title should be "What is the distribution of the ratio between independent Gamma and Beta random variables?".

Comment: What a cool answer

Comment: @Francis, is there a specific name for such distribution? Thanks!

Comment: @FelipeAugustodeFigueiredo: The papers simply called $U/V$ as gamma beta ratio distribution, so I guess $Y$ can be called beta gamma ratio distribution.

Comment: @Francis, would the moment for the so called beta gamma ratio distribution be the same as the one given in http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.bjps/1327328084 for the gamma beta ratio distribution, see page  187, section 6?

Comment: @Francis, I asked the question above because my final question on this topic, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253764/expectation-of-the-ratio-between-beta-and-gamma-random-variables, has to do with expectation, but this time it is the expectation of the ratio between a matrix with some Gamma distributed r.v.'s  and the squared sum of P Gamma r.v.'s. It's very similar to the problem above. Could you have a look, please? Thanks!

Comment: @FelipeAugustodeFigueiredo: You can use those formula as long as $n$ satisfies the conditions. Also noted that $E[Y]=E[Z^{-1}]$ and so on.

Comment: @Francis: would you mind taking a look at this question, please: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253764/expectation-of-the-ratio-between-beta-and-gamma-random-variables? I tried to split my problem in several questions but it seems it wasn't a good approach... The question I mention above (link) is the real problem I'm facing. Any hint would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @Francis, is there a proof why $U$ and $V$ are independent? You only said without any reference or proof. Could you provide some reference or proof, please?

Comment: @FelipeAugustodeFigueiredo see the Related Distributions section of this page: http://www.randomservices.org/random/special/Beta.html

Answer (score 5):

Francis has provided the definitive elegant solution. Following his beautiful method, it seems possible to produce a somewhat simpler form for the pdf.

In particular, following Francis' elegant solution, let $V \sim \text{Beta}(m,m)$ with pdf $f(v)$:

[image]

.. and let $U \sim \text{Gamma}(2m, c)$ where $U$ is independent of $V$, and let $Z = \frac1U$, so that $Z \sim \text{InverseGamma}(2m,c)$ with pdf $g(z)$:

[image]

Then the desired pdf of $Y = \frac{V}{U} = V Z$, say $h(y)$, can be found with:

[image]

where I am using the `TransformProduct` function from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica* to automate the nitty gritties.

**So does it work?**

Here is a quick Monte Carlo check of the:

- simulated pdf of $Y = \frac{A}{(A+D)^2}$  (generated from $A$ and $D$) (blue squiggly)
- compared to the exact theoretical pdf $h(y)$ (dashed red) derived above:

[image]

when parameter $m = 4$ and $c=3.01$. Looks fine.

Comment: could you have a look at the following question, please? stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253764/…. I think you might possibly help with that. Thanks!

Comment: No mention of the conflict of interest you have in advocating the use of said for-profit package? Funny how you tend to "forget" this...