# Expectation of the ratio between Beta and Gamma random variables

Tags: distributions, matrix, gamma-distribution, beta-distribution, ratio

Given
\begin{equation}\label{eq:definition_of_z}
\begin{split}
\textbf{Z} = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
{z}_{11} & {z}_{12} & \cdots & {z}_{1P} \\
{z}_{21} & {z}_{22} & \cdots & {z}_{2P} \\
{z}_{31} & {z}_{32} & \cdots & {z}_{3P} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
{z}_{M1} & {z}_{M2} & \cdots & {z}_{MP} \\ \end{array} \right] =  \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
\textbf{z}_{1} & \textbf{z}_{2} & \cdots & \textbf{z}_{P} \\ \end{array} \right]
\end{split}
\end{equation}

where $\textbf{z}_{i}$ represents each of the columns of  $\textbf{Z} \sim \mathcal{CN}(\textbf{0}_{M \times P},\text{cM}\textbf{I}_{P})$ and $z_{ij} \sim \mathcal{CN}(0,c)$.

Other necessary definition is given by

\begin{equation}\label{eq:definition_of_z_z}
\textbf{Z}^{H} \textbf{Z} =  \left[\begin{array}{c}
\textbf{z}_{1}^{H} \\
\textbf{z}_{2}^{H} \\
\vdots \\
\textbf{z}_{P}^{H} \\ \end{array} \right]  \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
\textbf{z}_{1} & \textbf{z}_{2} & \cdots & \textbf{z}_{P} \\ \end{array} \right] = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
\textbf{z}_{1}^{H}\textbf{z}_{1} & \textbf{z}_{1}^{H} \textbf{z}_{2} & \cdots & \textbf{z}_{1}^{H} \textbf{z}_{P} \\
\textbf{z}_{2}^{H} \textbf{z}_{1} & \textbf{z}_{2}^{H} \textbf{z}_{2} & \cdots & \textbf{z}_{2}^{H} \textbf{z}_{P} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\textbf{z}_{P}^{H} \textbf{z}_{1} & \textbf{z}_{P}^{H} \textbf{z}_{2} & \cdots & \textbf{z}_{P}^{H} \textbf{z}_{P} \\ \end{array} \right] 
\end{equation}

I'd like to know the following expectation:

\begin{equation}\label{eq:channel_matrix}
 \mathbb{E} \left\lbrace  \frac{ \textbf{Z}^{H} \textbf{Z} }{ \text{Tr} \left(    \textbf{Z}^{H} \textbf{Z}     \right)^{2} }    \right\rbrace = \mathbb{E} \left\lbrace  \frac{ \textbf{Z}^{H} \textbf{Z} }{ \left(   \textbf{z}_{1}^{H}\textbf{z}_{1} + \textbf{z}_{2}^{H}\textbf{z}_{2} + \cdots + \textbf{z}_{P}^{H}\textbf{z}_{P}     \right)^{2} }    \right\rbrace
\end{equation}

where $\text{Tr}$ is the Trace operator.

It is important to note that the elements of the main diagonal of $\textbf{Z}^{H} \textbf{Z}$, namely  $\textbf{z}_{1}^{H}\textbf{z}_{1}, \ \textbf{z}_{2}^{H}\textbf{z}_{2}, \ \cdots, \  \textbf{z}_{P}^{H}\textbf{z}_{P} \sim \Gamma(M,2c)$.

$\textbf{EDIT: 30/12/2016}$: So far we now from [What is the distribution of the ratio between independent Beta and Gamma random variables?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253607/what-is-the-distribution-of-the-ratio-between-independent-beta-and-gamma-random) the distribution of the ratio between independent Beta and Gamma random variables, $i.e.$,

\begin{equation}\label{eq:3}
y_1 = \frac{\textbf{z}_{i}^{H}\textbf{z}_{j}}{\left(   \textbf{z}_{1}^{H}\textbf{z}_{1} + \textbf{z}_{2}^{H}\textbf{z}_{2} + \cdots + \textbf{z}_{P}^{H}\textbf{z}_{P}     \right)^{2} }, \ \text{when} \  i = j.
\end{equation}

What is still missing is the distribution of the following ratio:

\begin{equation}\label{eq:4}
y_2 = \frac{\textbf{z}_{i}^{H}\textbf{z}_{j}}{\left(   \textbf{z}_{1}^{H}\textbf{z}_{1} + \textbf{z}_{2}^{H}\textbf{z}_{2} + \cdots + \textbf{z}_{P}^{H}\textbf{z}_{P}     \right)^{2} }, \ \text{when} \  i \neq j.
\end{equation}

Would the above function also have the same distribution as when $i = j$?

It's also worth mentioning that $\textbf{z}_{1}^{H}\textbf{z}_{1} + \textbf{z}_{2}^{H}\textbf{z}_{2} + \cdots + \textbf{z}_{P}^{H}\textbf{z}_{P}$ results in a scalar random variable.

Comment: Does someone know how to find the pdf of $y_2$? That would be a good starting point to find out the matrix's expectation. If I happen to know $\textbf{z}_{i}^{H}\textbf{z}_{i}$'s pdf when $i \neq j$, I could use prudentAI's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the following case I have found the following equation for its expectation

$$
 \mathbb{E} \left\lbrace y_1 \right\rbrace = \mathbb{E} \left\lbrace \frac{\textbf{z}_{i}^{H}\textbf{z}_{j}}{\left(   \textbf{z}_{1}^{H}\textbf{z}_{1} + \textbf{z}_{2}^{H}\textbf{z}_{2} + \cdots + \textbf{z}_{P}^{H}\textbf{z}_{P}     \right)^{2} } \right\rbrace = \frac{1}{2cP(MP-1)}, \ \text{when} \  i = j \ \text{and} \ MP \gt 1. $$

$\textbf{Proof}$:

Writing $y_1$ as

$$y_1  = \frac{V}{U}$$

where $V = \frac{\textbf{z}_{i}^{H}\textbf{z}_{j}}{   \textbf{z}_{1}^{H}\textbf{z}_{1} + \textbf{z}_{2}^{H}\textbf{z}_{2} + \cdots + \textbf{z}_{P}^{H}\textbf{z}_{P}  }$ and $U = \textbf{z}_{1}^{H}\textbf{z}_{1} + \textbf{z}_{2}^{H}\textbf{z}_{2} + \cdots + \textbf{z}_{P}^{H}\textbf{z}_{P}$ where $U \sim \Gamma(MP,2c) $ and $V \sim \beta(M,M(MP-1))$ are independent random variables.

Then taking into account that $V$ and $U$ are independent we have:

$$\mathbb{E} \left\lbrace y_1 \right\rbrace = \mathbb{E} \left\lbrace \frac{V}{U} \right\rbrace = \mathbb{E} \left\lbrace V \right\rbrace  \mathbb{E} \left\lbrace \frac{1}{U} \right\rbrace $$

Note that $\frac{1}{U}$ follows the inverse-gamma distribution and then if $U \sim \Gamma(MP,2c)$ thus $\frac{1}{U} \sim Inv-Gamma(MP,2c)$.

Next, the following expectations $\mathbb{E} \left\lbrace \frac{1}{U} \right\rbrace = \frac{1}{2c(MP-1)}, MP \gt 1$ and $\mathbb{E} \left\lbrace V \right\rbrace = \frac{1}{P}$ give us the final result.

Finally, I'm supposing (but I'm not sure as I haven't figured out the distribution of $\textbf{z}_{i}^{H}\textbf{z}_{j}$ when $ i \neq j$):

$$
\mathbb{E} \left\lbrace y_2 \right\rbrace = \mathbb{E} \left\lbrace \frac{\textbf{z}_{i}^{H}\textbf{z}_{j}}{\left(   \textbf{z}_{1}^{H}\textbf{z}_{1} + \textbf{z}_{2}^{H}\textbf{z}_{2} + \cdots + \textbf{z}_{P}^{H}\textbf{z}_{P}     \right)^{2} } \right\rbrace = 0, \ \text{when} \  i \neq j.
$$

Comment: Does someone know how to prove the assumption for the second expectation above? I've run some simulations on matlab and confirmed it is the right result but I'd like a proof for that.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t see an obvious way of finding an exact analytical solution, but you could fall back on Taylor expansions. As explained on the Wikipedia article on [Taylor expansions for the moments of functions of random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansions_for_the_moments_of_functions_of_random_variables#First_moment), the approximate expected value of the division of the random variable X by the random variable Y is

$\operatorname{E}\left[\frac{X}{Y}\right]\approx\frac{\operatorname{E}\left[X\right]}{\operatorname{E}\left[Y\right]} -\frac{\operatorname{cov}\left[X,Y\right]}{\operatorname{E}\left[Y\right]^2}+\frac{\operatorname{E}\left[X\right]\operatorname{var}\left[Y\right]}{\operatorname{E}\left[Y\right]^3}$

which you may be able to adapt to your matrix expressions. This approximation will likely be poor if there is an appreciable probability that the denominator is close to 0.