# Distribution of sum of fourth powers of two independent normal random variables

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, chi-squared-distribution

Let $X_1, X_2$ be i.i.d. $\sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$.

How can I find $P(X_1^4+X_2^4 < 3)$?

There is a similar [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253308/what-is-the-distribution-of-the-sum-of-squared-chi-square-random-variables), but instead of the sum of squares of $\chi^2_1$ the question is about the square of their sum.

It seems like a possible solution is to take the integral of joint density function of two normal random variables with those borders, but I'm wondering if a more elegant solution exists.

Comment: Would you be happy with an approximate numerical solution?