# normal distribution with square root or n-power

Tags: normal-distribution

I have a gaussian random variable N(0,sigma)

I know how to calculate probabilities like P(N>value) or P(N < value) thanks to Q-function.

I'd like to know how to calculate probabilities like P(sqrt(N)>value) or 
P(sqrt(N) < value).

And also probabilities like P(N^2>value) or P(N^2 < value)

Thanks really.

Answer (score 1):

That requires you to have the distribution of the transformed random variable. If $N$ is normal with mean zero and a certain variance, you find the distribution of its square, e.g., here: [Square of normal distribution with specific variance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93383/square-of-normal-distribution-with-specific-variance/122864)

As for the square root, that transformation is problematic, as a normal random variable has support on the entire real line, and that would amount to the possibility of taking the square root of a negative number.